# Vue add a component on button click

Tags: vue.js

I have three templates. AddCard.vue , ImageCard.vue and VideoCard.vue

AddCard.vue has two buttons on it one is to add the Image Card and Other To Add the video Card.. I need to add components based on the button click. Here are three templates and my index.html file.

index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                 <div class="container">
                    <div id="dynamic_components">
                     <!-- add components here -->
                    </div>
                    <addcard></addcard>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

AddCard.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="buttons">
        ul class="no-margin-list">
                                <li @click="imagecard">
                                  <span class="card_icon">
                                      <img :src="'img/image.jpg'" >
                                    </span>
                                    <p>Add Image Card</p>
                                  </a>
                                </li>

                            <li @click="videocard">
                                  <span class="card_icon">
                                      <img :src="'img/video.jpg'" >
                                    </span>
                                    <p>Add Video Card</p>
                                  </a>
                              </li>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
      imagecard(val) {
        //how to add image card
      },
      videocard() {
        //how to add video card 
      }
    },

  }
</script>
```

ImageCard.vue

```
<template>
    <h1> I am a image Card </h1>
</template>
<script>

</script>
```

VideoCard.vue

```
<template>
    <h1> I am a Video Card </h1>
</template>
<script>

</script>
```

I need to add components dynamically one after another in the `<div id="dynamic_components">` . User can add as many as cards  they want.

How do I add the components dynamically. Please point me to a tutorial.

Comment: Keep **data-driven** in mind. for your cases, define one array as data/computed property=cards like `[{'card-content':{}, 'card-type':'image'}, {'card-content':{}, 'card-type':'image'}]`, then in your template, `<div>
                     <!-- add components here --><template v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index" :is="card['card-type']"></template>
                    </div>`

Comment: @Sphinx , so each time the user clicks the button , I need to push the new array element in the computed property and v-for will take care of rendering it on the UI.

Comment: @Sphinx Please write an answer, you just provided a great answer but as a comment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uses [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) + [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('card1', {
  template: '<div>Card:<span style="background-color:green">{{title}}</span></div>',
  props: ['title']
})

Vue.component('card2', {
  template: '<div>Card:<span style="background-color:blue">{{title}}</span></div>',
  props: ['title']
})

Vue.component('card3', {
  template: '<div>Card:<span style="background-color:yellow">{{title}}</span></div>',
  props: ['title']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [
        {'card': {'title': 'I am one card1'}, 'card-type':'card1'},
        {'card': {'title': 'I am one card2'}, 'card-type':'card2'}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedNoCard1: function () {
      let availableCards = new Set(['card2', 'card3'])
      return this.cards.filter((item) => {
        return availableCards.has(item['card-type'])
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCard: function () {
      let supportedCards = ['card1', 'card2', 'card3']
      let seed = Math.floor(Math.random()*supportedCards.length)
      this.cards.push({'card': {'title': 'I am new card for ' + supportedCards[seed]}, 'card-type': supportedCards[seed]})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="addCard()">Add Card</button>
  <table>
  <tr><th>Data Property</th><th>Computed Property</th></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
      <component  :is="card['card-type']" :title="card.card.title">
      </component>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div v-for="(card, index) in computedNoCard1" :key="index">
      <component  :is="card['card-type']" :title="card.card.title">
      </component>
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: how do I pass the values from app.js to the template files. For example how to pass the value of message to the ImageCard.vue template file. When the user clicks the Image Card.